# Let $W$ be a $T$ invariant subspace then show that $W$ has a complementary $T$ invariant subspace if $T$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $W$ be a $T$ invariant subspace then show that $W$ has a complementary $T$ invariant subspace if $T$ is diagonalizable.

Now $T$ is diagonalizable then m.p.($T$) = $(x-c_1)\cdots(x-c_n)$.

Let $\beta_1= \{\lambda^1_1,\cdots,\lambda^1_{k_1}\},\cdots,\beta_k=\{\lambda^k_1,\cdots,\lambda^k_{k_k}\}$ be the basis of $N(T-c_1.I),\cdots,N(T-c_k.I)$.

Then $\mathcal{B} = \beta_1 \cup \cdots \cup \beta_k$ spans $V$.

Then $T_w = T|_W$ is also a diagonalizable linear operator. Then m.p.($T_w$)=$(x-c_{i_1})\cdots(x-c_{i_{d}})$ where $1\le d \le n$

Then $W = sp\{\mathcal{B'}\} = sp\{\lambda^{i_1}_{i_{n_1}},\cdots,\lambda^{i_1}_{i_{n_{r_1}}},\cdots,\lambda^{d}_{i_{n_d}}\}$

Then let $W' = sp\{\mathcal{B} - \mathcal{B'}\}$ is also a subspace such that $W' \cap W = \{0\}$ and dim($W$)$+$dim($W'$) = dim($V$).

Hence $V = W \bigoplus W'$.

Can someone go through my attempt? How do I rectify if it's wrong?

Comment: there are an awful lot of indices here so it is not easy to follow.  You can streamline this with strong induction ($\dim V=1$ is obvious) then once you get to $T_w = T|_W$ justify why this is diagonalizable (being annihilated by m.p.) if $\dim W = n$ or $\dim W = 0$ the result trivially follows and if $0\lt \dim W =r \lt n$ then induction hypothesis gives a basis for $W$ in terms of its eigenvectors... you can then construct $w'$ by using $n-r$ other (linearly independent) eigenvectors of $T$ as a basis

Comment: Yes,  this is what my argument has been since the mp of $T_w$ is a linear polynomial it is diagonalizable .$V$ is spanned by the eigenvectors of $T$ and $W$ will be spanned by some of the eigen-vectors of $T$ the remaining eigenvectors of $T$ will span $W'$ which is complementary to $W$. Where are we using induction?

Answer (score 1):

Let $c_1,…,c_k$ be distinct eigenvalues of $T$. Then minimal polynomial of $T$ is $(x-c_1)\cdots (x-c_k)$. $T_w$ is diagonalizable follows from “minimal polynomial of $T_w$ divides minimal polynomial of $T$” and “$T_w$ is diagonalizable$\iff$minimal polynomial of $T_w$ is product is distinct linear factor” fact. I assume $\mathcal{B}’$ is some subset of $\mathcal{B}$. But there need not exists $ \mathcal{B}’$ subset of $\mathcal{B}$ such that $\mathcal{B}’$ is basis of $W$. Following is counter example: Let $\{e_1,e_2\}$ be basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Consider a line $L$ passing through origin, angle it makes with $x$-axis is between $0$ and $90$ degree. $L$ is subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$ with dimension $1$. Then neither $\{e_1\}$ nor $\{e_2\}$ is basis of $L$. In linear algebra, “extending” of basis work. Unfortunately “shrinking” of basis don’t work. Your proof is wrong and I don’t see a way to rectify it.